# Google Apps Scripts no longer runs getActiveUser() within Sheets custom button triggers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

The following functions used to work but no longer work unless the scripts are ran inside the console. `Session.getActiveUser()` would usually run inside Google Sheets scripts assigned to an inserted drawing or a time based trigger. When the scripts are ran, `Session.getActiveUser()` only runs if I (the spreadsheet owner) run the scrip. If it's someone else, it either doesn't work or `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` outputs a blank string. To be clear, all scripts are ran within a spreadsheet environment. NOT a deployed web app.

```
function printEmail() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Test Stuff");

  var outputCell = ss.getRangeByName("testOutput");

  Logger.log(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());

  outputCell.setValue( Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
}

function printAdminEmail()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Test Stuff");

  var outputCell = ss.getRangeByName("testOutput");

  outputCell.setValue( Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail());
}
```

Here is a screenshot of attempting to run the script from a spreadsheet drawing. Returns blank. Drawing assigned to "printEmail"

[image]

Here is the JSON Manifest.

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "Sheets",
        "version": "v4",
        "serviceId": "sheets"
      },
      {
        "userSymbol": "DocsList",
        "version": "v1",
        "serviceId": "docs"
      },
      {
        "userSymbol": "Calendar",
        "version": "v3",
        "serviceId": "calendar"
      },
      {
        "userSymbol": "People",
        "version": "v1",
        "serviceId": "peopleapi"
      },
      {
        "userSymbol": "Tasks",
        "version": "v1",
        "serviceId": "tasks"
      }
    ]
  },
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly",
    "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly",
    "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify",
    "https://mail.google.com/",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks"
  ],
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "sheets": {
    "macros": [
      {
        "menuName": "sortCaseload",
        "functionName": "sortCaseload"
      },
      {
        "menuName": "df",
        "functionName": "df"
      }
    ]
  },
  "webapp": {
    "executeAs": "USER_ACCESSING",
    "access": "DOMAIN"
  }
}
```

Comment: When I tested your script of `printEmail()` by clicking the button by the owner of Spreadsheet and the user shared with the Spreadsheet, each email address can be retrieved and put into the range. So, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. In order to correctly replicate your situation of `If it's someone else, it either doesn't work or Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() outputs a blank string.`, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Does the person accessing your sheet have edit permission? I tried it on my end and `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` is working if the account has edit access.

Comment: @NikkoJ. They do have full edit permissions. I also tested it with my other personal email and it works for my other email but it doesn't work for another person with edit permissions.

Comment: @WilliamToscano - Did the other user authorize the script? There should be a pop up that will ask for the user's authorization. This happens when the user clicks the button for the first time.

Comment: @NikkoJ. I think they did. But just in case they didn't, how do they get the pop-up to come up again? Because when they run the script, it will still say "Running Script" but the compiler ignored anything involving getActiveUser().

Comment: @WilliamToscano - Try adding a new oauth scope to your manifest file.